# $A_n$ contains an isomorphic copy of $S_{n-2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Question is to prove that :

$A_n$ contains an isomorphic  copy of $S_{n-2}$

I have no idea from where to start.

I do not even believe this can be true (expect for cardinality conditions).

But as this is an exercise.it has to be true.

please provide some hints/suggestions to attack this problem.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $\;S_{n-2}\;$ acts on $\;\{1,2,...,n-2\}\;$ and $\;A_n\;$ on $\;\{1,2,..,n\}\;$ , then check the map

$$S_{n-2}\to A_n\;,\;\;\sigma\mapsto \begin{cases}\sigma\cdot(n-1\;\;n)&,\;\;if\;\;\sigma\notin A_{n-2}\\\sigma&,\;\;if\;\;\sigma\in A_{n-2}\end{cases}$$

with $\,\sigma\in S_{n-2}\;$ any permutation and $\,(n-1\;\;n)\;$ is the trasnposition.

Comment: I see this map is an injection. So, we have (assuming it is a homomorphism) $S_{n-2}\cong H\leq A_n$... Am i correct??

Comment: Yes, indeed...and it is a homomorphism.

Comment: yes, yes, I have now checked it, it is a homomorphism... I wonder "all of  a sudden " how can i think of such a strange map between $S_{n-2}$ and $A_n$... could you please specify if there is something more to think of such map.. or it is just like that...

Comment: I think there's all there is to it: we need *a difference* of two between $\,n-2\,,\,n\;$ in order to be able to stick that permutation there to make the map work (i.e., to "turn" odd permutations in $\;S_{n-2}\;$ into even ones in $\;A_n\;$). That's all.

Comment: ok,ok. I understood :)

Comment: So, all we are trying to do is Convert (give a map) an "odd permutation" in $S_{n-2}$ to "even permutation" in $A_n$ so that every element in $S_{n-2}$ has image in $A_n$ and make sure it is injective :)